# Trouble converting shapefile to DataFrame in Julia using ArchGDAL

Tags: julia, gis, gdal, dataframes.jl

I'm new to Julia and having some trouble working with geospatial data here. I'm working with a relatively large shapefile (BasinATLAS data here: https://www.hydrosheds.org/hydroatlas) where the layer of interest is about 1.3GB. I'm want to subset the data iteratively, and it seems easier to covert to a dataframe to do so.

I'm reading in the data fine:

```
myData = ArchGDAL.read("/shapefile.shp")
myLayer = ArchGDAL.getlayer(myData, 2)
```

And I can convert one of the small layers to a dataframe fine, too:

```
myDF = DataFrames.DataFrame(myLayer)
```

But when I try to read one of the chunkier layers (> 1GB) I get this error:

> GDALError (CE_Failure, code 1):
> Error in fread() reading object of size 1256 at offset 85982596 from .shp file

Is there a size limit on DataFrames.DataFrame()? And if so, is there an alternative way to manipulating the shapefile (removing rows, adding columns, calculations, etc.)?

*edit: and for clarity, the underlying data are fine. I regularly work with this database in R using the sf package. I'm just struggling to recreate that work in Julia using ArchGDAL.

Comment: I will be inclined to say that this is a problem with the file itself, can you extract the layer using `ogr2ogr` from the command-line?

Comment: I usually use R and I have no problem reading and manipulating the data using the sf package. I've never used ogr2ogr before, though.

Comment: The problem is probably on the `ArchGDAL` side. I tried your workflow with the file `BasinATLAS_v10_lev10.shp` and it worked fine, resulting in a `941012×295 DataFrame`. There is no theoretical size limit on DataFrames, other than your computer's own memory capacity (which isn't even a problem if you memory-map a file on disk). If you want something a bit more lightweight, consider the [`Shapefile`](https://github.com/JuliaGeo/Shapefile.jl) package, which lets you parse the shapefiles directly in Julia without relying on an external binary.

Comment: Thanks @JackShannon. I'm still not sure why ArchGDAL is acting strangely with the larger database. But the data are working fine with Shapefile.jl (and loading super fast). Thanks for taking the time!